# What is exactly a file-like object in Python?

Tags: python

From the [documentation for the standard library `json` module](https://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html#json.dump):

> `json.`**`dump`**`(`*`obj, fp, *, skipkeys=False, ensure_ascii=True, check_circular=True, allow_nan=True, cls=None, indent=None, separators=None, default=None, sort_keys=False, **kw`*`)`
>
> Serialize *obj* as a JSON formatted stream to *fp* (a `.write()`-supporting [file-like object](https://docs.python.org/3/glossary.html#term-file-like-object)) using this conversion table.

What exactly does this description mean? What object types are "`.write()`-supporting", and "file-like"?

Comment: Well, you answered your question yourself: really _any_ object that supports proper invocations of either read(), write(), or both, is considered to be a file-like object. It really can be any object you like - the joy of duck typing.

Comment: I don't think there's any official standard. Most interfaces should specify exactly the functionality they require. If you want to know if some other thing supports what is needed, you'll have to look at the docs for it or read its source code.

Comment: "File-like object" is, in fact, [precisely defined](https://docs.python.org/3/glossary.html#term-file-like-object).

Comment: In more recent versions of the documentation, this passage has been updated for `json.load` not to mention "file-like objects": "Deserialize fp (a .read()-supporting text file or binary file containing a JSON document) to a Python object using this conversion table." However, the `json.dump` description still mentions the concept. The documentation also hasn't used the `simplejson` name in approximately forever.

Comment: **Historical note**: The `json` standard library module was added in Python 2.6, and its documentation didn't include a link to explain the "file-like object" concept, nor did it mention that in the glossary. This library came from a third-party project called `simplejson`, some version of which was incorporated wholesale; documentation at the time may have mentioned the `simplejson` name, but current documentation for 2.6 does not. (Legacy documentation for 2.5 and before seems not to contain a glossary at all.)

Comment: I edited the question to show an example from the current documentation that does mention (and link) the concept, and to remove a section about motivation for the question (since it doesn't make sense with the changed example). If you are here because you are trying to figure out how to handle JSON from a web request (or close a question as a duplicate), like with OP's original motivation, please refer to the canonical: [How can I parse (read) and use JSON?](/questions/7771011).

Answer (score 13, accepted):

File-like objects are mainly `StringIO` objects, connected sockets and, well, actual file objects.

If everything goes well, `urllib.urlopen()` returns a file-like object supporting the necessary methods.

Comment: `the necessary methods`... this is the most important aspect.  Which methods?

Answer (score 28):

From the [glossary](https://docs.python.org/3/glossary.html):

> [**file-like object**](https://docs.python.org/3/glossary.html#term-file-like-object)
>
> A synonym for file object

and a file object is

> [**file object**](https://docs.python.org/3/glossary.html#term-file-object)
>
> An object exposing a file-oriented API (with methods such
>   as read() or write()) to an underlying resource. Depending on the way
>   it was created, a file object can mediate access to a real on-disk
>   file or to another type of storage or communication device (for
>   example standard input/output, in-memory buffers, sockets, pipes,
>   etc.). File objects are also called file-like objects or streams.
>
> There are actually three categories of file objects: raw binary files,
>   buffered binary files and text files. Their interfaces are defined in
>   the io module. The canonical way to create a file object is by using
>   the open() function.

Comment: "with methods such as" ... I suppose that really brings us back to the original question: what _exactly_ is this set of methods? Is e.g. "mode" a required attribute of such an object, or not?

Comment: @KlaasvanSchelven That, unfortunately, may depend on the underlying operating system or file system.

Comment: I suppose the question is rhetorical at this point ;-) The point being that we have different opinions on the meaning of "precisely defined"

Comment: "That, unfortunately, may depend on the underlying operating system or file system." Then it's not an API. Or at least not a single API. An API is a rigid interface; it's not conditional.

Answer (score 20):

[The *IO Class Hierarchy* section in the IO documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/io.html#class-hierarchy) contains a table listing the built-in and stub methods for the different types of file-like objects.

Basically, there is a hierarchy of abstract base classes:

- [`IOBase`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/io.html#io.IOBase), which promises little

  - [`RawIOBase`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/io.html#io.RawIOBase), which provides unbuffered binary IO
  - [`BufferedIOBase`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/io.html#io.BufferedIOBase), which provides buffered binary IO
  - [`TextIOBase`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/io.html#io.TextIOBase), which provides buffered string IO

To implement a file-like object, you would subclass one of the three descendants of `IOBase`, but not `IOBase` itself. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44584829/how-to-determine-if-file-is-opened-in-binary-or-text-mode) for attempting to determine which of these a given file-like object is.

Each of these classes provides various stub methods and mixins:

| Class | Stub Methods | Mixins |
| --- | --- | --- |
| `IOBase` | `fileno`, `seek`, `truncate` | `close`, `closed`, `__enter__`, `__exit__`, `flush`, `isatty`, `__iter__`, `__next__`, `readable`, `readline`, `readlines`, `seekable`, `tell`, `writable`, `writelines` |
| `RawIOBase` | `readinto`, `write` | `read`, `readall` |
| `BufferedIOBase` | `detach`, `read`, `read1`, `write` | `readinto`, `readinto1` |
| `TextIOBase` | `detach`, `read`, `readline`, `write` | `encoding`, `errors`, `newlines` |

The documentation for these methods can be found in the documentation for the classes, linked above.

Comment: Source for table: https://docs.python.org/3/library/io.html#class-hierarchy

Answer (score 17):

In Python, a *file object* is an object exposing an API having methods for performing operations typically done on files, such as `read()` or `write()`.

In the question's example: `simplejson.load(fp, ...)`, the object passed as `fp` is only required to have a `read()` method, callable in the same way as a `read()` on a file (i.e. accepting an optional parameter `size` and returning either a `str` or a `bytes` object).

This does not need to be a real file, though, as long as it has a `read()` method.

A *file-like object* is just a synonym for *file-object*. See [Python Glossary](https://docs.python.org/3/glossary.html#term-file-like-object).

Answer (score 5):

This is the API for all file-like objects in the Python standard library (as of 3.10.5).

```
# All file-like objects inherit the IOBase interface:
# Documented at https://docs.python.org/3/library/io.html#io.IOBase .
    close() -> None
    closed() -> bool # Implemented as @property `closed`
    fileno() -> int
    flush() -> None
    isatty() -> bool
    readable() -> bool
    readline(size: int = -1) -> Union[str, bytes]
    readlines(hint: Union[int, None] = None) -> list
    seek(pos: int, whence: int = io.SEEK_SET) -> int # SEEK_SET is 0
    seekable() -> bool
    tell() -> int
    truncate(pos: int = None) -> int # The parameter is named "size" in class FileIO
    writable() -> bool
    writelines(lines: list) -> None
    __del__() -> None
# Documented at https://docs.python.org/3/library/io.html#class-hierarchy .
    __enter__()
    __exit__(*args) -> None:
    __iter__()
    __next__() -> Union[str, bytes]
# Documented in paragraph at https://docs.python.org/3/library/io.html#io.IOBase .
# Note that while the documentation claims that the method signatures 
# of `read` and `write` vary, all file-like objects included in the Python 
# Standard Library have the following exact method signatures for `read` and `write`:
    read(size: int = -1) -> Union[str, bytes]
    write(b: Union[str, bytes]) -> int # The parameter is named "s" in TextIOBase
```

Specific file-like objects may implement more than this, but this is the subset of methods that are common to ALL file-like objects.

Comment: This is true for the standard library only. In many places in the Python world (even on [docs.python.org](https://docs.python.org)) "file-like object" is a far looser notion. In many cases, having a `read(size: int)` method will be sufficient.

Answer (score -1):

simplejson has the calls **loads** and **dumps** that consumes and produce strings instead of file like objects.

This link has an example in the context of StringIO and simplejson for both file-like and string objects.

http://svn.red-bean.com/bob/simplejson/tags/simplejson-1.3/docs/index.html