# TypeError: argument 1 must have a "write" method

Tags: python, python-3.x, csv

My problem at hand is to get the data from API's and input that data into csv. I'm able to get the data, however outputting the data into csv is where I'm getting the error. Can someone please help.

Here is the sample code:

```
import csv,sys  
def read_campaign_info(campaigns):
   myfile = csv.writer(open("output.csv", "w")) 
   for insight in reach_insights:
            account_id = str(insight[AdsInsights.Field.account_id])
            objective = str(insight[AdsInsights.Field.objective])
            metrics =[account_id,objective]
            wr = csv.writer(myfile,quoting=csv.QUOTE_ALL)
            wr.writerows(metrics)
```

Type of variable `metrics` is `<class 'list'>`

Error that I'm getting is

```
wr = csv.writer(myfile,quoting=csv.QUOTE_ALL)
TypeError: argument 1 must have a "write" method
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You are passing a `csv.writer()` object to `csv.writer()`:

```
myfile = csv.writer(open("output.csv", "w")) 
wr = csv.writer(myfile,quoting=csv.QUOTE_ALL)
```

`myfile` is a `csv.writer()` object *already*. Pass your rows to that instead, or remove the `csv.writer()` call from the `myfile` line (but then move the `wr = csv.writer(..)` line out of the loop, you only need to create this once).

I strongly recommend you use the file object as a context manager so it is closed properly. Also, you want to leave newline handling to the CSV module, so use `newline=''` when opening the file:

```
with open("output.csv", "w", newline='') as myfile:
    wr = csv.writer(myfile, quoting=csv.QUOTE_ALL)
    for insight in reach_insights:
        account_id = insight[AdsInsights.Field.account_id]
        objective = insight[AdsInsights.Field.objective]
        wr.writerow([account_id, objective])
```

The `csv.writer()` object handles conversions to string for you, so the `str()` calls are redundant.

Comment: Thank you for the comment. I modified the code to 'wr = csv.writer(metrics,quoting=csv.QUOTE_ALL)', but still it has the same error. Can you show how to modify my code. Sorry, I'm noob in python

Comment: @user4943236: `metrics` is your row, not a file object. You already created a `csv.writer()`, you don't need to keep creating one in the loop.

Comment: thanks, I modified my code to do the following `   myfile.writerows(metrics) `, now this is the error that I'm getting, any idea how to resolve this
 > Error: iterable expected, not float

Comment: @user4943236: did you try and modify your code to follow the example in my answer instead? You now appear to have no `csv.writer()` object at all.

Comment: I did and it worked except one issue. The issue was that it was adding one character in one column instead of one complete value in one column. any idea why could be the case

Comment: @user4943236: ah, I had missed you used `csv.writer.writerows()` (plural), that should be `csv.writer.writerow()` (singular, no `s` at the end). Corrected.

Comment: More generally, you are getting this error because the object passed into `csv.writer()` as `myfile` did not have a `write()` method, which is generally a sign that it was expecting a file-like object.  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4359495/what-is-exactly-a-file-like-object-in-python