# Different Between download_file and download_fileobj in boto3?

Tags: python, amazon-s3, boto3

i want to download files which are in amazon s3. And i have used boto3 sdk and i want to know the different between download_file and download_fileobj in boto3?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From the [documentation](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/s3.html#S3.Client.download_file), it is mentioned that:

> download_file(Bucket, Key, Filename, ExtraArgs=None, Callback=None, Config=None)
>
> Download an S3 object to a file.

and

> download_fileobj(Bucket, Key, Fileobj, ExtraArgs=None, Callback=None, Config=None)
>
> Download an object from S3 to a file-like object. The file-like object must be in binary mode. This is a managed transfer which will perform a multipart download in multiple threads if necessary.

One is file, the other one is file-like object with binary mode.

Comment: Let's give the OP the benefit of the doubt and assume they read this much.

I think the info in the docs arguably still begs the question:  What, exactly, is a "file-like object"?

Comment: Ahh, "file-like object" is just a file object.  See https://stackoverflow.com/a/58861402/310441

Answer (score 0):

Here is a good primer and documentation to explain things:
https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/guide/s3-example-download-file.html

For example,

```
import boto3

s3 = boto3.client('s3')
s3.download_file('BUCKET_NAME', 'OBJECT_NAME', 'FILE_NAME')
```

and

```
s3 = boto3.client('s3')
with open('FILE_NAME', 'wb') as f:
    s3.download_fileobj('BUCKET_NAME', 'OBJECT_NAME', f)
```

In particular, it says they have "identical functionality."