# Redirect python stdout to a tempfile

Tags: python, stdout

I am aware of: [Redirect stdout to a file in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4675728/redirect-stdout-to-a-file-in-python)

I'm asking how to go about the following:

```py
In [2]: with tempfile.NamedTemporaryFile() as tmp:
   ...:     contextlib.redirect_stdout(tmp):
   ...:         print('this')
```

Which errors with:

```
TypeError: a bytes-like object is required, not 'str'
```

From the docs (https://docs.python.org/3/library/contextlib.html#contextlib.redirect_stdout):

> Context manager for temporarily redirecting sys.stdout to another file or file-like object.

Searching for which gave me this post: [What is exactly a file-like object in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4359495/what-is-exactly-a-file-like-object-in-python) which states:

> An object exposing a file-oriented API (with methods such as read() or write()) to an underlying resource

Which made me think perhaps the following would work:

```py
In [2]: with tempfile.NamedTemporaryFile() as tmp:
   ...:     contextlib.redirect_stdout(tmp.file):
   ...:         print('this')
```

as `tmp.file` has `read` and `write` from `dir(tmp.file)` (so, is "file like" ? ).

This still errors though, with the same error message.

So, how should I go about redirecting standard out to a temporary file?

Comment: You're missing a `with` before `contextlib.redirect_stdout(tmp)`. So `with contextlib.redirect_stdout(tmp): ...`

Answer (score 1):

This way, it seems to work:

```
with tempfile.NamedTemporaryFile(mode='w') as tmp:
    with contextlib.redirect_stdout(tmp):
        print('this')
```

NB: the default value for 'mode' is 'w+b'